# How can i check if file exist with ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-native

i am building a mobile app for both android and iOS i want to check if a directory exist in the users sd card or in-built memory, if the directory doesn't exist, then i will create the directory.
I checked the docs on [ionic file transfer docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-transfer) but i can't find anything useful, i searched online but found some code but its not working, the name of the directory that I want to create is softik, Here is the code

```
public storageDirectory:any;
download() {
    this.chkmkDir().then(async ()=>{
        const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.fileTransfer.create();
        this.storageDirectory = `${this.file.externalRootDirectory}test.mp4`;
        fileTransfer.onProgress((progressEvent)=>this.progress=Math.round((progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total) * 100))
        fileTransfer.download(this.url,this.storageDirectory + 'test.mp4', true).then((entry) => 
            console.log('Berhasil download dan tersimpan di : ' + this.storageDirectory + "test.jpeg"), 
            error => console.log('gagal : ' + JSON.stringify(error)),
        );  
    }).catch(err=>console.log())
}
chkmkDir(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        this.file.checkDir(this.file.externalRootDirectory, 'softik').then(res=>resolve()
        ).catch(err => {
            this.file.createDir(this.file.externalRootDirectory, 'softik',false).then(res =>resolve())
            .catch(err=>reject(JSON.stringify(err))); 
        });
    })
}
```

Pls what am i going wrong

Answer (score 0):

first you should use File plugin
then you can search for file or Directory
see this docs https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/file/#checkFile